# custom fortify rule with android

Tags: android, rules, fortify

I'd like to write a fortify rule that looks for instances of "addJavascriptInterface" in android codebases.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RulePack xmlns="xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/rules">
    <RulePackID>80B927D2-5408-41B4-B47C-B4958DAAECBD</RulePackID>
    <SKU>SKU-80B927D2-5408-41B4-B47C-B4958DAAECBD</SKU>
    <Name><![CDATA[android.xml]]></Name>
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <Description><![CDATA[Description for android.xml]]></Description>
    <Rules version="3.13">
        <RuleDefinitions>
            <SemanticRule formatVersion="3.13" language="java">
                <MetaInfo>
                    <Group name="Accuracy">5.0</Group>
                    <Group name="Impact">5.0</Group>
                    <Group name="RemediationEffort">15.0</Group>
                    <Group name="Probability">5.0</Group>
                </MetaInfo>
                <RuleID>CC4B8F82-0824-4DF1-8A5F-513DC6820B99</RuleID>
                <VulnCategory>Testjsinterface</VulnCategory>
                <DefaultSeverity>5.0</DefaultSeverity>
                <Description/>
                <Type>default</Type>
                <FunctionIdentifier>
                    <NamespaceName>
                        <Pattern>\w*</Pattern>
                    </NamespaceName>
                    <ClassName>
                        <Pattern>WebView</Pattern>
                    </ClassName>
                    <FunctionName>
                        <Pattern>addJavascriptInterface</Pattern>
                    </FunctionName>
                    <ApplyTo implements="true" overrides="true" extends="true"/>
                </FunctionIdentifier>
            </SemanticRule>
        </RuleDefinitions>
    </Rules>
</RulePack>
```

When I tried to run fortify against a codebase, I got the following :-

```
[warning]: The following references to java classes could not be resolved. Please make sure to supply all the required jar files that contain these classes to SCA.
    Override
    android.app.Activity
    android.content.res.AssetManager
    android.os.Bundle
    android.util.Log
    android.view.KeyEvent
    android.webkit.WebSettings
    android.webkit.WebView
    android.webkit.WebViewClient
```

So i tried running fortify as follows :-

```
bin/sourceanalyzer ~/repos/android-rule-tests/WebViewTest -cp ~/android-sdks/platforms/android-16/android.jar
```

The warning goes away but the rule still does not seem to fire -- what could be going wrong?

EDIT
For clarity, WebViewTest is a sample project which uses addJavascriptInterface.

EDIT2
Added some code for clarity

```
package org.infil00p.phoneTest;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.infil00p.phoneTest.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    WebView appView;
    TestWebViewClient testClient;
    String TAG="FAILTAG";
    Bolt data = new Bolt();
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        testClient = new TestWebViewClient();

        appView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.appView);
        appView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        appView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        appView.addJavascriptInterface(data, "test");

        appView.setWebViewClient(testClient);

        appView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    }
    ....
```

EDIT3
I played around with this a bit and eventually reached the conclusion that in my particular case a semantic rule would not fire, until it saw a function thats defined in a class in the same file. Getting the android sources and copying over the source of WebView.java causes the rule to fire(a horrible thing to do but im just playing around).

Comment: The missing JARs had nothing to do with the custom rule not working. This is a common error when scanning Java apps.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet or URL for the source to WebViewTest?

Comment: I've added part of the code for clarity.

Comment: I also tried running it against multiple open source libraries like https://github.com/beaucollins/android-hybrid-demo ; and the effect is still the same.

Comment: Semantic rules are not a straight GREP. It only looks at code that is used in the program. What is the program's entry point? Android does not have a traditional "main()", so it should be something like "onCreate". http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would advise the pattern for namespace to be `.*`. Secondly, where are you saving the custom rule file to? If not in `<SCA install>/Core/config/customrules` then it needs to be specified with the `-rules` option. 
Also you are missing a build ID, your commands should be something like:

```
sourceanalyzer -b test -clean
sourceanalyzer -b test -source 1.6 ~/repos/android-rule-tests/WebViewTest -cp ~/android-sdks/platforms/android-16/android.jar -rules /path/to/rules/file.xml
sourceanalyzer -b test -scan -f myResults.fpr
```

I think with Android there's also an R class file created at runtime. Because SCA doesn't do this, the project should be built first so this can be specified in the classpath somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

1. CLEAN CACHE: ~/sourceanalyzer -b test -clean
2. TRANSLATE (no need to mention -filter, -rules, -project-template during code translation): ~/sourceanalyzer -b test -source 1.6 ~/repos/android-rule-tests/WebViewTest -cp ~/android-sdks/platforms/android-16/android.jar
3. SCAN (where rules/filters/template being specified): ~/sourceanalyzer -b test -filter 'absolute_path_file.txt' -rules 'absolute_path_rulename.xml' -scan -f myResults.fpr

if you place the custom_rule.xml to the FORTIFY_HOME/Core/config/rules/ directory (along with the HP rulepacks), you can omit the -rules parameter during scan.